# Why do I need to have a virtual property with EF5 in my child class?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity Framework 5 with Code First and lazy loading disabled. Given the following:

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Credits { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}

// Mapping Relationships for Course

<code here>
this.HasRequired(t => t.Department)
.WithMany(t => t.Courses)
.HasForeignKey(d => d.DepartmentID);
```

Can someone explain why I would need to have the:

```
public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
```

What would happen if I **completely remove this line**? What would I not be able to do? As far as I can see the only thing I could not do is to use Entity Framework to check my foreign key. However I already have this set up in the database so I would still get an error from the Db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Department property exists as a link to a specific department for a course.
It can be part of a one to many relationship which gives you access to a department from a course.

Comment: The DepartmentId is useful, but the Department Property contains all the columns of the Department entity. It's handy if you need to get details about the department (Name etc) - while working with a Course

Answer (score 1):

It contains your `Department` information, `Depertment Name` `Courses` information.I think you can remove it because the information of `Department` you can also access by searching for its `DepartmentID`. But it would be better to keep it.

Comment: Thanks. I did try to remove it but then it gave me an error for the mapping. I added the code for the mapping so you can see. Is there another way I could do the mapping if I remove the line?